# Is there a way in C++ to "compare" a string with a typename?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a json with initial values and a manager that creates objects.
The values are read as string but the manager needs the typename to create the object.

I have something like this

```
for(auto obj_str : json["objs"])
{
    if(obj_str == "ObjectFoo")
    {
        manager.createObject<ObjectFoo>();
    }
    if(obj_str == "ObjectBar")
    {
        manager.createObject<ObjectBar>();
    }
    if(obj_str == "ObjectBaz")
    {
        manager.createObject<ObjectBaz>();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid using an if statement per object with one or more generic functions?
The string of the object is always the same as the typename.

Comment: There is no way to automatically do this. Consider using a `std::map<std::string, /*member function pointer*/>`

Comment: [`typeinfo`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/typeinfo) and some template cleverness could probably do it. I'll post an answer in a bit if no one beats me to it.

Comment: C++ does not really have introspection capabilities. I’m sure it is possible to kludge up something using typeinfo, but it would be either implementation-specific or a large, fragile library to do something relatively simple. Sometimes it is OK to have a single function with a large `if` — though, honestly, this would be best as an unordered_map, IMHO, which can be decoupled from initialization/registration code for each type.

Comment: With a bit of luck, you can go from a type to a string using `typeinfo`. But you cannot go the other way around without building a table of some sort that maps between strings and types. An if-else chain is one form of such table, not the most terse one, but there is no way around enumerating all the types by hand.

Comment: `typeinfo` won't be portable, and may not work even from run-to-run of the same executable.  It may happen to work, until you switch compilers, or switch versions of the same compiler.

Comment: Before I think about this any further, do all the objects have a common ancestor type? (If so, google around “c++ object factory”.) If not, things get more interesting :-)

Answer (score 3):

Although there may be some other way of doing that which does not involve an `if` statements, there will have to be somewhere, in some form or fashion, some code that translates between strings and discrete types.

This is fundamental to C++: the types of all objects and expressions must be known, and determined, at compile time. This is hard, immutable rule, and there are no exceptions, and you are running into this fundamental, core C++ principle.

Instead of an `if` statement, other possibilities include an associative container that maps a class name to a closure that instantiates an object of the given type, or receives whatever this `manager` object is, as a parameter, and calls the manager's template method using the associated class name.

Or there could be something completely external to C++, a script of some kind that reads a configuration file, in some structured format, and spews out robo-generated C++ code that consists of the above `if` statements, then integrated into your development build system, so that it gets built and rebuilt automatically, when needed.

But the short answer to your question is: unfortunately no, C++ just doesn't work this way. The value of `obj_str` is not known until run time. The type that any C++ expression or statement uses must be known at compile time, that's it. There is no way to reconcile this fundamental disconnect. In some form, or fashion, you will need to implement the code and logic that will check and validate `obj_str` for each possible value and instantiate the appropriate type, accordingly.